# Discrete metric separable is countable

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

> How do I show that if I have a discrete metric space $X$ which is separable then it is countable?

As $X$ is separable, it contains a countable, dense subset $S$.
The metric on $X$ is defined by

$d(x,y)=1$ if $x\neq y$

$d(x,y)=0$ if $x= y$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A set $D\subseteq X$ is dense in $X$ if and only if $D$ intersects every non-empty open set in $X$. If $X$ is discrete, $\{x\}$ is open for each $x\in X$, and $D\cap\{x\}\ne\varnothing$ if and only if $x\in D$. Thus, the only dense subset of a discrete space is the whole space, and in order for the space to have a countable dense subset, it must itself *be* countable.

Answer (score 3):

You know that there is some countable subset $D \subset X$ such that its closure is $X$ ($D$ is dense in $X$).

But $D$ is a closed set of $X$, because you have the discrete topology on $X$. Therefore $X=\overline D = D$ is countable.

You don't need any metric on $X$ to prove this (notice that saying "a discrete metrizable space" is a pleonasm…).